# Applet troubles

Tags: java, html, applet, embed

I'm trying to embed an applet in my site, but I can't for the love of God figure out why this won't work! I have a JAR file called `BHSurveyor.jar` with my class that extends `javax.swing.JApplet` in it at `bhs.gui.GUIApplet`. Now, i've already tried embedding it in a page, and I've tried everything from

```
<applet codebase="/dist/" archive="/dist/BHSurveyor.jar" code="bhs.gui.GUIApplet" width="256px" height="256px" />
```

(in a locally opened HTML file one folder level below the JAR) to

```
<applet codebase="file://localhost/C:/Users/Supuhstar/Documents/NetBeansProjects/BHSurveyor/dist/" archive="file://localhost/C:/Users/Supuhstar/Documents/NetBeansProjects/BHSurveyor/dist/BHSurveyor.jar" code="bhs.gui.GUIApplet.class" width="256px" height="256px" />
```

and all permutations thereof, and thensome... but each and every time, I get the same red "Error. Click for details" message (which gives no details). **Can someone tell me what to do, here?**

### My setup

---

A full recreation of my setup can be viewed at http://s.supuhstar.operaunite.com/s/content/test/

### Testing

---

As suggested, I ran

```
jar -tvf BHSurveyor.jar
'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Assuming they meant something else, I tried

```
java -jar -tvf BHSurveyor.jar
Unrecognized option: -tvf
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

So you see this doesn't help... Again, running from assumptions, I ran this and got what I hope was the expected output:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\jar" -tvf BHSurveyor.jar
     0 Mon Aug 29 11:56:10 EDT 2011 META-INF/
   228 Mon Aug 29 11:56:08 EDT 2011 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Mon Aug 29 11:56:10 EDT 2011 bhs/
     0 Mon Aug 29 11:56:10 EDT 2011 bhs/gui/
  2264 Mon Aug 29 11:56:08 EDT 2011 bhs/AnswerType.class
  1851 Mon Aug 29 11:56:08 EDT 2011 bhs/DefPage.class
  1965 Mon Aug 29 11:56:10 EDT 2011 bhs/DefQuestion.class
  1463 Mon Aug 29 11:56:10 EDT 2011 bhs/DefTitlePage.class
  1338 Mon Aug 29 11:56:10 EDT 2011 bhs/Main.class
   615 Mon Aug 29 11:56:08 EDT 2011 bhs/Page.class
   786 Mon Aug 29 11:56:10 EDT 2011 bhs/Question.class
   402 Mon Aug 29 11:56:10 EDT 2011 bhs/TitlePage.class
  1757 Mon Aug 29 11:56:10 EDT 2011 bhs/Utils$1.class
   766 Mon Aug 29 11:56:10 EDT 2011 bhs/Utils$2.class
  6188 Mon Aug 29 11:56:10 EDT 2011 bhs/Utils.class
  3409 Mon Aug 29 11:56:10 EDT 2011 bhs/gui/GUIApplet.class
  1218 Mon Aug 29 11:56:10 EDT 2011 bhs/gui/GUIJFrame.class
  3549 Mon Aug 29 11:56:10 EDT 2011 bhs/gui/GUIPage.class
   824 Mon Aug 29 11:56:10 EDT 2011 bhs/gui/GUIQuestion$1.class
  8650 Mon Aug 29 11:56:10 EDT 2011 bhs/gui/GUIQuestion.class
```

### Applet constructor and init

---

```
  public GUIApplet(Page... pgs)// throws UnknownHostException
  {
    System.out.println("new GUIApplet(Page... " + pgs + ")");
//    System.out.println(java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
    System.out.println("  setting layout...");
    setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

    System.out.println("  adding components...");
    addComponents();

    System.out.println("  initializing pages...");
    pages = new ArrayPP<>();

    System.out.println("  installing pages...");
    int i=1;
    for (Page p : pgs)
      if (p != null)
        installPage(p);
    System.out.println("  changing look-and-feel...");
    LookAndFeelChanger.setLookAndFeel(LookAndFeelChanger.NIMBUS);
    System.out.println("  fixing nav buttons...");
    fixNavButtons();
    System.out.println("GUIApplet complete");
  }

  public void init()
  {
    // TODO start asynchronous download of heavy resources
    System.out.println("GUIApplet.init()");
  }
```

Comment: **Moderator note** _Comments under this question were purged because they degraded into noise. Please, keep comments constructive._

Comment: It was *not* the output I expected, but that is progress, and I have another theory to pursue.  I'll get back to you soon(ish).

Comment: That constructor would not be called by the VM because it accepts arguments.  The `init()` method is empty.  That is *one* reason that no components would appear in the applet.  Why does the single constructor throw a `HeadlessException`?  It seems a bit over the top to declare something that should never happen in an applet (or at least, I don't see how it could happen).  Sprinkle some `System.out.println()` methods throughout the constructor and put one in `init()` so we can trace what it is doing (which methods/constructors called) and what lines of the code complete successfully.

Comment: Done and done. http://s.supuhstar.operaunite.com/s/content/test/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<applet 
    codebase="/dist/" 
    archive="/dist/BHSurveyor.jar" 
    code="bhs.gui.GUIApplet" 
    width="256px" 
    height="256px" />
```

Change that to..

```
<applet 
    codebase="dist/" 
    archive="BHSurveyor.jar" 
    code="bhs.gui.GUIApplet" 
    width="256" 
    height="256" >
</applet>
```

Note: By my count there are 5 differences between those 2 `applet` elements.

---

#### Codebase

```
<applet 
    codebase="file://localhost/C:/Users/Supuhstar/Documents/NetBeansProjects/BHSurveyor/dist/" 
    ..
```

Some close examination of that codebase absolute path prompted me to make further comments.

I doubt there is any such path as shown.  Copy/paste it into a browser address bar and hit enter (always a good 'acid test' for file based paths).

Do you get the directory listing?

I suspect it should be:

`file:///C:/Users/Supuhstar/Documents/NetBeansProjects/BHSurveyor/dist/`

(i.e. without `localhost`).

There is also a special significance to the initial `/` in a codebase or similar path.  It equates to 'the root of the site'.  That means that your other codebase of `/dist/` would *actually* point to

`file:///C:/dist/`

What result do you get for that path in the browser?

BTW - neither of those questions are rhetorical.  To best help you, I need answers.

---

#### Update on test page

> A full recreation of my setup can be viewed at http://s.supuhstar.operaunite.com/s/content/test/

It appears as though [BHSurveyor.jar](http://s.supuhstar.operaunite.com/s/content/test/dist/BHSurveyor.jar) contains text, at least it is [returning a content-type of `text/html`](http://pscode.org/mime/applet.html?media.url=http%3A%2F%2Fs.supuhstar.operaunite.com%2Fs%2Fcontent%2Ftest%2Fdist%2FBHSurveyor.jar&mime.type=application%2Fjava-archive&ua.string=).  And the console is being very helpful..

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.deploy.util.DeployAWTUtil.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.runOnEDT(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException: bhs.gui.GUIApplet
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$12.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: bhs.gui.GUIApplet
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    ... 15 more
Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

---

#### Update on applet in local testing

After downloading the Jar locally, (encountering a different error, then installing JDK 7 to fix it), I am finally in a position to see what you described.

> "Error. Click for details" message (which gives no details).

1. Firstly, note that you can use the cross-compilation options to compile a Java 1.5 (or whatever previous version) in the version 7 JDK.  A handy tip to know when it comes time for deployment.
2. But most importantly..

   - Are there any try/catch statements in the applet `init()` method?  Does the applet have a (non-default) constructor?  If so, same question re try/catch.
   - If it is not too long or too private, what is the code (copy/pasted) of the `init()` and constructor parts of the applet source?

My latest theory (as to the primary problem with the applet loading) is that there are `try`/`catch` statements that are swallowing or ignoring exceptions.  Beyond that, I am at a loss as to why the applet would not load, yet not show any relevant output in the Java Console.

As an aside, the fact that the server is returning the wrong content-type for the Jar should be fixed, though it seems it is not the underlying problem here.

Comment: when I copy-paste `file:///C:/Users/Supuhstar/Documents/NetBeansProjects/BHSurveyor/dist/` into my browser, it redirects me to `file://localhost/C:/Users/Supuhstar/Documents/NetBeansProjects/BHSurveyor/dist/`... I'm assuming that's just Opera, though.

Comment: I've put it on my site and changed it to `<applet codebase="/s/content/test/" archive="http://s.supuhstar.operaunite.com/s/content/test/dist/BHSurveyor.jar" code="bhs.gui.GUIApplet" width="256" height="256"></applet>`, but it still doesn't work! See my latest edit if you wanna take a look at my code and setup

Comment: Alright, so I didn't get ANY of that in my Java console... dunno what happened there. Anyway, none of that is from my code, so how do I fix it?

Comment: Wait.. I notice something here... I've been compiling this with the UTF-8 character set. Should I not be?

Comment: Is there a way to tell the webpage/browser I'm using the UTF-8 character set?

Comment: Forget all that for the moment.  I think you missed the significance of me saying that the Jar contains text.  Try running `jar -tvf BHSurveyor.jar` and copy/paste the output into your question.

Answer (score 2):

You did several mistakes.

1. `archive` is must be relative to codebase. It means that if your jar is under `dist` folder you should say: `<applet codebase="/dist/" archive="BHSurveyor.jar"` or `<applet codebase="/" archive="/dist/BHSurveyor.jar"` (unless your jar is actually under `/dist/dist/BHSurveyor.jar`)
2. Most applet tag examples show that they write `.class` suffix in the value of code attribute, so in your case write: code="bhs.gui.GUIApplet.class" (as you did in second example where codebase and archive seem  to be completely wrong.
3. Although most HTML elements support unites when writing width and height I have never seen that this is supported in case of applets, so remove `px`: `width="256" height="256"`

Use Applet console. It can be started from menu of your browser. Probably you will see some kind of exception there that will help you to understand what the problem is.

If all this does not help, do the following.

1. Check you applet with `appletviewer` or using your IDE. Be sure that it is able to run.
2. Put it somewhere under web server and check manually URL to its JAR file. You should be able to download jar using browser (or wget command).
3. If this does not work too, go there: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/applet.html, take the applet tag from this site. Try to understand it. Copy/paste it to your HTML and make it working. Then replace codebase archive to yours and pray :).

Good luck.

Comment: I replaced the applet tag with `<applet codebase="/dist/" archive="BHSurveyor.jar" code="bhs.gui.GUIApplet.class" width="256" height="256">Enable Java!</applet>`, and it's still the same story :<

Comment: Re. your point 2 in the 1st section.  The `code` attribute should be the fully qualified class name.  Adding ".class" at the end is tolerated, but not correct.

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew, I used applets more than 10 years ago last time, so I probably do not remember. .class is what I saw in many examples I found.

Comment: @Supuhstar have Andrew's suggestions helped you? Did you try my other suggestions (appletviewer etc)

Comment: Unfortunately many of Sun/Oracle's own examples in the Java Tutorial and other sample codes do exactly that (incorrectly add the `.class` extension to the FQN).  I take it as a personal crusade to educate people - especially when those people are offering help for applet problems.  BTW - noted the '1.4' nature of your link (which also adds `.class`) is missing from the 1.5 online docs.  Check [Applet Deployment](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_deployment.html) in the Java 7 docs - not a `.class` to be seen.  Could go on, but running out of comment..

Comment: See also the notes on the leading `/` in a path, in the edit to my answer.

Comment: see my latest comment on his answer

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking in the Java console? For example in IE: Tools->Internet Options->Advanced you'll see an option to enable the console. You may well see some useful error messages there.